# Angular - unit conversion

Tags: javascript

In an Angular app, I'm showing a value in "l/h" unit, but I do a conversion to store this value in "kg/s" in my database. For example, if the user enters 30 l/h, I store 30 **/ 0.9506 / 3600** = 0.008766393155200223

Then, when the user refreshes the page, the value displayed is not 30 but 29.999999999999993 (the result of 0.008766393155200223 *** 0.9506 * 3600**).

How could I avoid this conversion side-effect?

Comment: You can't.  It's a consequence of how all IEEE-754 floating-point math works.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken  I suppose you could store the original entry, not the computed result?

Comment: Just round it. Math.round()

Comment: Or use angular decimal pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JavaScript can't handle correctly floating points, in our Angular app we have been using the '[big.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/big.js/)' library to deal with the the decimal operations.

Installation:

```
npm install big.js
npm install @types/big.js
```

Import:

```
import Big from 'big.js';
```

Comment: Perfect! you saved me :)